# Sorting list of matrices by the first column

Tags: r, list, sorting, matrix

I have a list containing 4 matrices, each with 21 random numbers in 3 columns and 7 rows.

I want to create new list using lapply function in which each matrix is sorted by the first column.

I tried:

```
#example data
set.seed(1)
list.a <- replicate(4, list(matrix(sample(1:99, 21), nrow=7)))

ordered <- order(list.a[,1])

lapply(list.a, function(x){[ordered,]})
```

but at the first step the R gives me error `"incorrect number of dimensions"`. Don't know what to do. It works with one matrix, though.

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: You need to find the `order` for each matrix in the list. Does this `lapply(list.a, function(x) x[order(x[,1]),])` work?

Comment: @user20650 IMO you should do that and earn the rep for providing the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there - but you would need to iterate through the list to reorder each matrix.

Its easier to do this is one `lapply` statement

```
lapply(list.a, function(x) x[order(x[,1]),])
```

Note that `x` in the function call represents the matrices in the list.